# Перемещение камеры

Tags: c#, unity3d

1. Хочу реализовать скрипт, который будет перемещать камеру, при зажатой ЛКМ (и с помощью движения мышки) перемещаться вокруг объекта.
2. В моменты, когда пользователь будет крутить колесико - будет эффект зума (без измненея Field Of View).
3. Использую UI 4.6, имеется окно, со списком, который скролится. Как сделать так, что бы при открытии окна, скролл сразу переходил к нужному элементу (даже если он находится в середине списка или в самом низу).

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Я всегда думал что на стэк приходят пополнить багаж знаний, а не просить сделать что то за тебя.

Answer (score 4):

Лучше делить вопросы на разные в стэке, а не сваливать все в одну кучу.
1) У меня для полетов используется следующий скрипт:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class FlightScript : MonoBehaviour {

public Transform Target = null;

#region Keyboard
public float VelocityForward = 1.0f;
public float VelocityRight = 1.0f;
#endregion

#region Mouse
public enum RotationAxes { MouseXAndY = 0, MouseX = 1, MouseY = 2 }
public RotationAxes axes = RotationAxes.MouseXAndY;

float rotationY = 0F;
float rotationX = 0F;
#endregion

public float MaxRotationSpeed = 100.0f;
private float currentRotationSpeed = 0.0f;
private float timeRemainRSpeed = 5.0f;

public float MaxPower = 4f;
private float power = 0.3f;
private Texture2D tBack;
private Texture2D tBar;
private Vector3 velocity = Vector3.zero;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () 
{
    if (Target == null) Target = transform;
    tBack = new Texture2D(1,1);
    tBack.SetPixel(0, 0, new Color(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f));
    tBack.Apply();
    tBar = new Texture2D(1,1);
    tBar.SetPixel(0,0, new Color(1f, 0f, 0f, 0.7f));
    tBar.Apply();
    // Make the rigid body not change rotation
    if (Target.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>())
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().freezeRotation = true;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () 
{
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    UpdateFunction();
}

void OnGUI()
{
    GUI.skin.box.normal.background = tBack;
    GUI.Box(new Rect(5,5, 104, 14), tBack);
    float m = power/MaxPower;
    GUI.skin.box.normal.background = tBar;
    Rect rect = new Rect(7f,7f, 100f * m, 10f);
    GUI.Box(rect, tBar);
}

void UpdateFunction()
{
    float doublePower = Input.GetAxis("Double");
    doublePower = doublePower > float.Epsilon ? 2 : 1;
    power += Input.GetAxis("Power");
    power = Mathf.Clamp(power, 0.3f, MaxPower);

    MouseUpdate();
    Quaternion AddRot = Quaternion.identity;
    rotationX *= Time.fixedDeltaTime*MaxRotationSpeed*doublePower;
    rotationY *= Time.fixedDeltaTime*MaxRotationSpeed*doublePower;
    AddRot.eulerAngles = new Vector3(-rotationY, rotationX, 0);
    Target.rotation *= AddRot;

    AddRot = Quaternion.identity;
    float roll = Input.GetAxis("Roll");
    float pitch = Input.GetAxis("Pitch");
    float yaw = Input.GetAxis("Yaw");
    //Debug.Log(power);
    roll *= (Time.fixedDeltaTime * MaxRotationSpeed * doublePower);
    pitch *= (Time.fixedDeltaTime * MaxRotationSpeed * doublePower);
    yaw *= (Time.fixedDeltaTime * MaxRotationSpeed * doublePower);
    AddRot.eulerAngles = new Vector3(-pitch, yaw, -roll);
    Target.rotation *= AddRot;
    Target.position += VelocityForward * Target.forward * Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * power * doublePower;
    Target.position += VelocityRight * Target.right * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * power * doublePower;
}
void MouseUpdate()
{
    if (!Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        rotationX = 0;
        rotationY = 0;
        return;
    }
    rotationX = 0;
    rotationY = 0;
    if (axes == RotationAxes.MouseXAndY)
    {
        rotationX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");

        rotationY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");

    }
    else if (axes == RotationAxes.MouseX)
    {
        rotationX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
    }
    else
    {
        rotationY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");
    }
}

}
```

Соответственно в `Input` надо добавить оси:

- `Double` - двойное ускорение действия,
- `Power` - чувствительность движения и поворота для клавиатуры,
- `Yaw`, `Pitch`, `Roll` - рысканье, тангаж и крен соотвтественно.

Если вы хотите чтобы камера не пролетала через другие объекты вешайте на объекты коллайдеры, а на камеру колайдер чуть большего размера чем передний план на камере, остальное за вас сделает физика.

2) Без изменения FOV вам придется расчитывать расстояние на которое сдвинуть камеру вручную чтобы получить эффект изменения Масштаба.

3) Для того чтобы выбрать элемент в списке вам придется искать его в этом списке по некоему признаку, например имени и устанавливать фокус, определять позицию в объекте где он лежит и выставлять скролл вектор.

Answer (score 1):

1. Использую следующий скрипт, он для тача, но вроде бы работает и для мыши. Если нет, всегда можно подменить способ ввода.

   ```
       private Vector2 worldStartPoint;

       void Update()
       {

           // only work with one touch
           if (Input.touchCount == 1)
           {
               Touch currentTouch = Input.GetTouch(0);

               if (currentTouch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
               {
                   this.worldStartPoint = this.getWorldPoint(currentTouch.position);
               }

               if (currentTouch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
               {
                   Vector2 worldDelta = this.getWorldPoint(currentTouch.position) - this.worldStartPoint;

                   GetComponent<Camera>().transform.Translate(
                       -worldDelta.x,
                       -worldDelta.y,
                       0
                   );
               }
           }
       }

       // convert screen point to world point
       private Vector2 getWorldPoint(Vector2 screenPoint)
       {
           RaycastHit hit;
           Physics.Raycast(GetComponent<Camera>().ScreenPointToRay(screenPoint), out hit);
           return hit.point;
       }
   ```
2. Попробуйте такой скрипт

   ```
    float scrollSpeed = 0.5f;

       void Update()
    {
       cameraDistance += Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") * scrollSpeed;
    }
   ```
3. Что из себя представляет список? Вероятно начальный скрол должен устанавливаться в привязанном к нему скрипте в методе `Start()`

Comment: 1. Почему Vector2? Могу ли я просто поменять на Vector3, если у меня 3D? 2. Делал подобную реализацию, как защититься от того, что камера может въехать в объект? 3. Список - обычный список, с перечнем элементов, сделан с помощью Scroll Rect, Mask и ScrollBar.

Comment: 1. Когда щелкаете по экрану сложно определить глубину клика, поэтому есть только X и Y, которые проецируются на поверхность. 2. Вам нужно определить ограничения. Для этого есть метод `cameraDistance = Mathf.Clamp(cameraDistance, cameraDistanceMin, cameraDistanceMax);`

Comment: По поводу скролла: начальное значение инициализируется в Start(), но, каким методом я могу просчитать значение value в Scrollbar, что бы скролл опустился до нужной мне позиции, если кол-во элементов в списке может изменяться? NumOfSteps, кажись, не может быть больше 13(как он вообще влияет на scroll?)